# Show procedure code in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, source-code

I've tried to show the SQL code of a stored procedure called `add_pixel`:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE CODE add_pixel;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I've made sure that the procedure exists:

```
mysql> CALL add_pixel();
ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE pixels.add_pixel; expected 3, got 0
```

And `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` works:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_pixel;
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Procedure | sql_mode | Create Procedure | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| add_pixel |          | NULL             | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | utf8_unicode_ci    |
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and that my MySQL version supports `SHOW PROCEDURE ([SHOW PROCEDURE CODE was added in MySQL 5.0.17](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-procedure-code.html)).

How do I view the source SQL code of the procedure?

Comment: Try [`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html)

Comment: As your link explains about the `SHOW PROCEDURE CODE`: *"This statement is a MySQL extension that is available only for servers that have been **built with debugging support**."*

Comment: @ypercube `SHOW CREATE` works. I think you might be right about the debugging support. Care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**

Amazingly enough, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`  does not have a param-list column.

You can use `mysql.proc`. For example, looking at a procedure of mine:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE name='run' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  db: common_schema
                name: run
                type: PROCEDURE
       specific_name: run
            language: SQL
     sql_data_access: MODIFIES_SQL_DATA
    is_deterministic: YES
       security_type: INVOKER
          param_list:
  in query_script text

             returns:
                body: main_body: begin
  if (LEFT(query_script, 1) in ('/', '\\')) and (LEFT(query_script, 2) != '/*') then
    begin
          declare query_script_file_name text;

      set query_script_file_name := query_script;
      set query_script := LOAD_FILE(query_script_file_name);
      if query_script is null then
        call throw(CONCAT('Cannot load script file: ', query_script_file_name));
      end if;
    end;
  end if;
  call _interpret(query_script, TRUE);
end
             definer: root@localhost
             created: 2012-08-17 17:24:46
            modified: 2012-08-17 17:24:46
            sql_mode:
             comment: Run given QueryScript text
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
        db_collation: latin1_swedish_ci
           body_utf8: main_body: begin
  if (LEFT(query_script, 1) in ('/', '\')) and (LEFT(query_script, 2) != '/*') then
    begin
          declare query_script_file_name text;

      set query_script_file_name := query_script;
      set query_script := LOAD_FILE(query_script_file_name);
      if query_script is null then
        call throw(CONCAT('Cannot load script file: ', query_script_file_name));
      end if;
    end;
  end if;
  call _interpret(query_script, TRUE);
end
```

Look for the `param_list` column (I believe that was your main concern).
Also look for `db`, `name`, `type`.

=================

Alternatively, can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`. For example, looking at a procedure of mine:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME='run' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       SPECIFIC_NAME: run
     ROUTINE_CATALOG: NULL
      ROUTINE_SCHEMA: common_schema
        ROUTINE_NAME: run
        ROUTINE_TYPE: PROCEDURE
      DTD_IDENTIFIER: NULL
        ROUTINE_BODY: SQL
  ROUTINE_DEFINITION: main_body: begin
  if (LEFT(query_script, 1) in ('/', '\')) then
    begin
          declare query_script_file_name text;

      set query_script_file_name := query_script;
      set query_script := LOAD_FILE(query_script_file_name);
      if query_script is null then
        call throw(CONCAT('Cannot load script file: ', query_script_file_name));
      end if;
    end;
  end if;
  call _interpret(query_script, TRUE);
end
       EXTERNAL_NAME: NULL
   EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE: NULL
     PARAMETER_STYLE: SQL
    IS_DETERMINISTIC: YES
     SQL_DATA_ACCESS: MODIFIES SQL DATA
            SQL_PATH: NULL
       SECURITY_TYPE: INVOKER
             CREATED: 2012-08-17 17:24:46
        LAST_ALTERED: 2012-08-17 17:24:46
            SQL_MODE: 
     ROUTINE_COMMENT: Run given QueryScript text
             DEFINER: root@localhost
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT: utf8
COLLATION_CONNECTION: utf8_general_ci
  DATABASE_COLLATION: latin1_swedish_ci
```

In particular, look at the columns `ROUTINE_SCHEMA`, `ROUTINE_NAME`, `ROUTINE_TYPE`, `ROUTINE_DEFINITION`. These provide most of the interesting data.

Comment: I should note that the above only applies to MySQL **5.1**. As of MySQL **5.5** there's the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` table which provides routine params.